# Assign project site template to EPT

Tags: project-online, sitetemplate

[image: Grey out option Site Template]

I was trying to change **site template** with site that I had saved. The target site was using project site template and the solution was activated. Checking on [Microsoft site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enterprise-project-types-c576de02-a25c-4ea1-9de6-02be44dbb0a6), I don't understand what this **if it appropriate** means. Is there something that I need to do before I could setup this project site template.
[image: If appropriate]

Answer (score 0):

I knew I have to do something to make it enable. In Site Creation option you need to choose either Automatically create a site on next publish or Allow users to choose.
[image]
it then became enable.